# Is it possible to modify duplicated links box?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10641709/908879) was closed because being a duplicate, however, only one of the two links in the box is correct.

Is there a way we can remove the other link?

Comment: Is it not possible to edit it out?

Comment: The Community edit is an edit like any else; it can be modified at will.

Comment: @murgatroid99 wow, actually it is, I didn't know

Comment: I've approved your suggested edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Automatic edits inserted by the community user don't lock a post from further manual edits.

Just take care to preserve the formatting; use the Markdown that's already there as a reference.

Please also do not edit these out (or add new ones in) on a whim; discuss in the comments which questions are appropriate as duplicates and which are not. If in doubt, flag for moderator attention and we'll help decide if the edits are warranted.

Comment: Should be noted that normally these should not be edited out. When I first read this question and your answer I thought you were giving everybody the green light to modify duplicate links at will.

Comment: @slhck: I missed that; added a warning to my answer.